# How to determine the partial derivative of a concatenation of a vector and a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Suppose $\mathbf{x}$ is an $n$ dimensional vector and $y$ is 1 dimensional. We define $\mathbf{z}=(\mathbf{x},y)$ which is the concatenation of $\mathbf{x}$ and $y$. Given that $\mathbf{V}$ is a PSD matrix, how is it possible to find the derivative of $\| \mathbf{z}\|_{\mathbf{V}}$ (where $\| \mathbf{z}\|_{\mathbf{V}}\ =\sqrt{ \mathbf{z}^\top \mathbf{V}\mathbf{z}}$) with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ and $y$ separately as a closed form solution?

Comment: You can find the derivative wrt $z$ first, then extract the first components to get the derivative wrt $x$, and the last components to get the derivative wrt $y$.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Consider a slightly more general case in which $y$ is also a vector
$$\eqalign{
x\in\R{n}\quad y\in\R{m}\quad z\in\R{k}\qquad k=m+n 
}$$
Partition the identity matrix
$$\eqalign{
I_k &= \mc{I_n&0\\0&I_m} = \mc{E&F} \\
E^TE &= I_n,\quad F^TF=I_m \\
E^TF &= 0,\quad\;\, F^TE=0,\qquad EE^T + FF^T=I_k \\
}$$
and use the partitions to relate the vectors
$$\eqalign{
z &= Ex+Fy \qiq x=E^Tz,\;\;y=F^Tz \\
}$$
The same formula can also be applied to the respective gradients
$$\eqalign{
g &= Ep+Fq \qiq p=E^Tg,\;\;q=F^Tg \\
\\
g &= \grad{\phi}{z},
\qquad p=\grad{\phi}{x},
\quad q=\grad{\phi}{y}
\\
}$$
The remaining task is to calculate $g\,$ (which many previous posts on this site have done).

Comment: Thank you so much. Does $\Phi$ show $\| \mathbf{z} \|_{\mathbf{V}}$?